# monthly payment calculator

Tags: java, logic

I have some code which I find to keep giving me a dividing by 0 error.
It is suppose to calculate the monthly payment amount!

```
import java.io.*;

public class Bert
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    //Declaring Variables
    int price, downpayment, tradeIn, months,loanAmt, interest;
    double annualInterest, payment;
    String custName, inputPrice,inputDownPayment,inputTradeIn,inputMonths, inputAnnualInterest;
    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

   //Get Input from User
    System.out.println("What is your name?  ");
    custName = dataIn.readLine();
    System.out.print("What is the price of the car?  ");
    inputPrice = dataIn.readLine();
    System.out.print("What is the downpayment?  ");
    inputDownPayment = dataIn.readLine();
    System.out.print("What is the trade-in value?  ");
    inputTradeIn = dataIn.readLine();
    System.out.print("For how many months is the loan?  ");
    inputMonths = dataIn.readLine();
    System.out.print("What is the decimal interest rate?  ");
    inputAnnualInterest = dataIn.readLine();

    //Conversions
    price = Integer.parseInt(inputPrice);
    downpayment = Integer.parseInt(inputDownPayment);
    tradeIn = Integer.parseInt(inputTradeIn);
    months = Integer.parseInt(inputMonths);
    annualInterest = Double.parseDouble(inputAnnualInterest);




            interest =(int)annualInterest/12;
            loanAmt = price-downpayment-tradeIn;

            //payment = loanAmt*interest/a-(1+interest)
            payment=(loanAmt/((1/interest)-(1/(interest*Math.pow(1+interest,-months)))));
    //Output
    System.out.print("The monthly payment for " + custName + " is $");
    System.out.println(payment);
            // figures out monthly payment amount!!!
}
}
```

the problem occurs when attempting to set the payment variable.
i don't understand why it keeps coming up with dividing by 0 error.

Comment: what is the value of `annualInterest`?  If it's less than 12 this will happen...

Comment: can we have some sample inputs as well

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your variables as Int so `1/interest` and `1/(interest*Math.pow(1+interest,-months))` will return 0. Change the type of your variables to float or double.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion to you, is that you should learn to "backwards slice" your code.

This means that when you see that you're getting a `DivideByZeroException` you should look at your code, and say, "why could this happen?"

In your case, let's look at this:

```
payment=(loanAmt/((1/interest)-(1/(interest*Math.pow(1+interest,-months)))));
```

So, now, `Math.pow` will never return anything zero (as it's a power), so it must be the case that `interest`is zero.  Let's find out why:

```
interest =(int)annualInterest/12;
```

So now, integer division in Java *truncates*.  This means that if you have .5 it will be cut off, and turned into zero.  (Similarly, 1.3 will be truncated to 0).

So now:

```
annualInterest = Double.parseDouble(inputAnnualInterest);
```

This implies that you are passing in something that gets parsed to a value that is less than 12.  If it were greater than 12 then you would get something else.

However, you might just be passing in an invalid string, for example, passing in `"hello2.0"` won't work!

Answer (score 0):

This will be rounding always to 0. So it is trowing exception.

```
   (1/interest)-(1/(interest*Math.pow(1+interest,-months)))));
```

Use [float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) type instead of [int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Learn how they works.

Answer (score -1):

```
package computeloan;




import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputeLoan {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print(" Enter Yearly Interest Rate : ");

        double annualIntersetRate = input.nextDouble();




        double monthlyIntersetRate = annualIntersetRate / 1200;




        System.out.print(" Enter Number of years :  ");


        int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();


        // Enter loan amount


        System.out.print(" Enter Loan Amount : ");


        double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();


        double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyIntersetRate /(1-1/Math.pow(1+monthlyIntersetRate,numberOfYears*12 ));





        double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * numberOfYears * 12;
        //Calculate monthlyPaymeent and totalPayment

        System.out.println(" The Monthly Payment Is : " +(int)(monthlyPayment*100) /100.0);





        System.out.println(" The Total Payment Is : " +(int)(totalPayment*100) /100.0 );
    }
}
```